# image-map in TYPO3 fluid templates

Tags: php, typo3, imagemap, fluid, extbase

i'm writing a extension for TYPO3 with extbase and fluid. Herein I want to show an image-map. The problem with that is, that the fluid engine wraps my <map>-tag with all its <area>-tags in  double-quotes and outputs them within a <p>-tag.

```
<map></map>
```

becomes

```
<p class="bodytext">    &lt;map&gt;</p>
<p class="bodytext">    &lt;/map&gt;</p>
```

i allready tried wrapping it within the following view-helpers

```
<f:format.{raw,html,...}>
<![CDATA[]]>
```

does anyone had this problem before?

#### Edit:

```
<f:layout name="Default" />
This Template is responsible for creating a table of domain objects. If
you modify this template, do not forget to change the overwrite settings
in /Configuration/ExtensionBuilder/settings.yaml: Resources: Private:
Templates: List.html: keep Otherwise your changes will be overwritten
the next time you save the extension in the extension builder

<f:section name="main">
 <f:image src="{f:uri.resource(path:'Images/Basemap.png')}"
  alt="Basemap" class="map" id="map" usemap="#StateLocations" />
 <table id="test"></table>
  <f:format.raw>
   <div id="themap"></div>
  </f:format.raw>
  <f:flashMessages />
  <f:format.raw>
   <map></map>
  </f:format.raw>
 </f:section>
```

#### Edit2:

```
<div class="tx-myext">
 <f:render section="main" />
</div>
```

Comment: No, i use them within the extension-template, in my case Resources/Private/Templates/Location/ShowMap.html.

Comment: I edited my original post.
The <div id="themap"> is there for a very ugly js-hack with which i am not very lucky...

Comment: I attached it, not very complex... It was generated by the extension builder extension.

Comment: Weird, have no idea, it looks like you were wrapping whole section with f:format.html, but you don't... can't help you, sry.

Comment: Interestingly it is only within the extension template. If i put the map in the main template, it goes right into the site...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the f:format.html viewhelper without any parsefunc like

```
<f:layout name="Layout" />
<f:section name="MySection">
    <f:format.html parseFuncTSPath=""><map></map></f:format.html>
</f:section>
```

I dont really know why you have to wrap the map-tag, but in my testcase it works without any parsefunction.

**Edit:**

```
<map></map> <!-- output <map></map> -->
<f:format.html parseFuncTSPath=""><map></map></f:format.html> <!-- output <map></map> -->
<f:format.html><map></map></f:format.html> <!-- output <p class="bodytext">&lt;map&gt;&lt;/map&gt;</p> -->
```

Comment: Same problem.... can you paste your layout- and template-file, so i can test it on my system?

Comment: which fluid version do you use?

Comment: The one who is bundeled with typo3 6.1.5, which is, accordingly to the extension manager, version 6.1.0.

Comment: i use the same versions and everything works very well. my last idea is to delete all caches, or you have some overwrites of the *stdWrap*

Comment: Not from what i am seeing... Neither within my typo3-template, nor in my extensions ext_typoscript_{constants,setup}.txt.
I'm deleting the caches all the time, so i don't think that this is the problem...

Comment: You can also check, if the problem ist the same in a blank new typo3.